# How the spring container starts and ways to load the spring container

Tags: java, spring

I want to know how actually the spring container gets loaded on server.. and in how many ways can that be done
and exactly how the server comes to know that it has to start the spring container.
I tried to google it but no luck.

Comment: *"I tried to google it but no luck."* - Did you try reading the Spring documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solutions is to use a `ContextLoaderListener`:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/web-integration.html for details.

Comment: and if we are not using web.xml and all the configuration is being done using WebApplicationInitializer, so in that case how the server will come to know that it has to take configuration from the class implementing the WebApplicationInitializer,